# Website is still not getting displayed in the Google search page.How to upload sitemap.xml file in Google

Tags: google-search-console

Hii I have created a website with the help of community builder of salesforce and used webmasters to display it in the Google search list.

Previously I was getting this message :[image]

Now after 2 days of creation of this website in webmasters I am getting the below message:

[image]

But still I am not able to see my website in the Google search page whenever I type any keyword related to the website

This is the first time my team is using webmasters .How much more time will it take for my website to be visible in the Google search page.
Please guide me.Thanks in advance

Comment: It has only been a couple of days. It can take weeks. Search engines are not real time. The Internet is just too huge.

Comment: Hi @closetnoc .It will take some time I understand but I just wanted to know where do I need to upload the sitemap.xml file that I created for this website.

Comment: I see that you edited this question to add a second question to the title.   Instead of doing that, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

SEO is a long term process and you may not get a result so soon.

Currently your website doesn't seem to load. First thing, make sure your website loads properly in the browser.

Then, user the following to see if Google has indexed any of your pages. Once pages will be indexed then you can start thinking about how to rank for particular keyword.

Type site:yoursite in Google to see if any of your pages have been indexed.

```
site:yoursite.com
```

Here are some steps you can take to improve your presence.

1. Make sure your website works perfectly in browser.
2. Create XML sitemap of your website and place it on root of your website. And notify Google using Google webmaster tools.
3. Worth sharing your pages on Social media.
4. Make sure you got proper meta title and description in your pages.

Step 1 - 3 will help you index your pages in Google. It may take few days for your pages to be indexed in Google.

Step 4 and there are many more which you need to work on to rank your website.

Comment: Thank you for the answer TopQnA. I followed each and every steps as you said .I have created an XML site map of my website.But when I am trying to place it on the root of my website and clicking submit in the webnmasters tool I am getting an error " 
We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.".How to resolve it?

Comment: It sounds like your path may be not right. Do this: make your file name as sitemap.xml and place it in root. Then try and locate it like: example.com/sitemap.xml. If you can locate in the browser then submit in Google webmaster tools and it should work.

Comment: Hi TopQnA , we have actually developed the website through salesforce and we have named the url of the website through GoDaddy.com. In the 2nd step we have to upload the sitemap.xml file in the File Manager of the webserver .Since, we are using webmasters tools is there any Folder name "File Manager " in the webmasters tools where we can upload the sitemap.xml file.If not where do we exactly need to upload the file.Please guide

Comment: Path to point your sitemap in Webmaster tools: Webmaster >> Dashboard >> Click on sitemap on right-hand side >> Add / Test Sitemap >> in the box type sitemap.xml (It should be same as your sitemap file name on the server) >> Submit.

Comment: TopQnA I tried doing that but first I have to upload the fiie which I am going to add to the root of my website.So, I have gone through many web documents where it was mentioned that I have to upload the sitemap.xml file in the web server first.Where do I need to upload this file that's what I was asking

Comment: I think i have provided your plenty of info, you can load it in root folder of your hosting.